# Javascript find nested object by value

Tags: javascript, pojo

**Summary of Problem**

I'm still learning Javascript and I know this may be basic but I'm having some trouble.

I have a object containing nested objects and I need to check if any of the nested objects have a property that matches a specific value.

**Code**

I want to check the object below to see if const eSportsUsername = "Dark" exists and return a Boolean.

```
Const object = {
   Dark: {_id: "5da78b305f0cc7fc44417821", online: false, eSportsUsername: "Dark"},
   HighDistortion: {_id: "5da78b505f0cc7fc44417825", online: false, eSportsUsername: "HighDistortion"}
}
```

Can anyone recommend how to achieve this?

Comment: you could use `obj.hasOwnProperty('a')` if exist only you need to check if online is true

Comment: As long as your object is not overwhelmingly large, recursion is the way to go. Have you given this approach a try?

Comment: I need to check if eSportsUsername equals a specific string, eg eSportsUsername: 'Dark'.  Will that still work?

Comment: @Andrew, I have tried that, how would I do that?  The object has 2 to 100 objects inside of it

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to get the values.
 dot notation as per the example
 or bracket notation

```js
const object = {
   Dark: {_id: "5da78b305f0cc7fc44417821", online: false, eSportsUsername: "Dark"},
   HighDistortion: {_id: "5da78b505f0cc7fc44417825", online: false, eSportsUsername: "HighDistortion"}
}

console.log(object['Dark']['eSportsUsername']);
//or
console.log(object.Dark.eSportsUsername);

//to return a boolean 
 let boolean = '';
if(object.Dark.eSportsUsername == "Dark")
{
boolean =  true;

}else {
boolean = false;
}

console.log(boolean);
```

Comment: I believe OP is referring to an object of arbitrary nesting

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

```
Object.values(object).some(obj => obj.eSportsUsername === "Dark") // will return true if any of the nested object has property with "Dark"
```

**Explanation**

In order to do this, you should

- first: convert the object into array of property values
- second: iterate through the array to check if an element has {eSportsUsername: "Dark"}

First step is achieved using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). In your example, `Object.values(object)` will return

```
[{eSportsUsername: "Dark", online: false}, {eSportsUsername:"HighDistortion", online: false}]
```

For the second step, we can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate the array and check if any nested object has `eSportsUsername` value as `"Dark"`.

Answer (score 0):

Used recursion to match value in nested object. This will work with and without key.

*Just post in comment if you want a solution without recursion*

**ref:** `Array.prototype.entires` and `Array .prototype.some`

```js
const input = {
  Dark: {
    _id: "5da78b305f0cc7fc44417821",
    online: false,
    eSportsUsername: "Dark"
  },
  HighDistortion: {
    _id: "5da78b505f0cc7fc44417825",
    online: false,
    eSportsUsername: "HighDistortion"
  }
};

const isExist = (obj, val, key) => Object.entries(obj)
  .some(([k, v]) => {
    if (v instanceof Object) { 
      // [] instanceof Object -> true
      // {} instanceof Object -> true
      // "abc" instanceof Object -> false
      // 123 instanceof Object -> false
      // null instanceof Object -> false
      // undefined instanceof Object -> false
      
      return isExist(v, val, key);
    }

    const keyMatched = !key || k === key;

    return keyMatched && (v === val);
  });


console.log(isExist(input, 'Dark', 'eSportsUsername'));
console.log(isExist(input, 'HighDistortion', 'eSportsUsername'));
console.log(isExist(input, 'Dark', 'unknown'));
console.log(isExist(input, '5da78b305f0cc7fc44417821'));
```

Comment: be careful with `typeof v === 'object'`. `typeof null` is `object`